# Pages with tables creating problem in print, even i'm using seperate Print css?

Tags: css, xhtml, printing

Pages with `tables` creating problem in print? **First page coming blank** and content comes in print from 2nd page if pages are having `<table>`

and if `table` is long i want to print `table` heading on each print page also.

```
    body{
        font: 8pt/1.5 Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background: white;

    }

    #wrap-threeContainer, #wrap-twoContainer, #header {width: auto; 
        padding-top:1em;background:none}

    #wrap-threeCenterColContainer, 
    #wrap-twoRightColContainer {margin:0;padding:0;width:auto;float:none}
    h1 {color:#000}

    #globalWrapper{
        width: auto; 
        margin: 0 2%;
        padding: 0; 
        border: 0;
        float: none !important;
        color: black; 
        background: transparent;
        }

    #dataContainer, #introTextContainer, #wrap-threeContainer h1  {width:100%}

    #top-bar, #primarynavcontainer, #breadcrumbsContainer, 
#footer, #wrap-threeLeftColContainer, #wrap-threeRightColContainer, 
#bannerContainer, p.update, .adobe-reader-download,
 #wrap-twoLeftColContainer {visibility:hidden; display:none}


      tr, td, th {page-break-inside:avoid}
      thead {display:table-header-group}

    a {color:#000000}



    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #520;
        background: transparent;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }
    #content a:link:after, #content a:visited:after {
       content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
       font-size: 90%;
       }

    div#dataContainer {

        }

    #header #logoContainer {
    position:static;
    }

    #header {border-bottom:1px solid #333}
```

Comment: Can you show the print stylesheet that you are using?

Comment: @KatieK - when i see page by css print media using "Web developer Toolbar" it looks fine but not in actual print and print preview function of browser. other pages are working fine which doesn't have `<table>`

Comment: @MGS - Any difference between Firefox, IE8, IE7 et cetera?

Comment: I'm talking about Firefox 3.6 . on others I haven't checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I solved this problem on my own. and sharing for other SO users , bcoz it can be helpful.

Wherever `overflow:hidden` was defined for layout's `div` in my screen css I overided all instances to `overflow:visible` in print css. and problem solved.